# How to change the value of the parameter in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

NOTE: There is no fix url for it. Means it is not possible to see this url always. I want code which works for all the urls.

For ex, http://januapp.com/demo/search.php?search=aaa
        http://januapp.com/demo/search.php?other=aaa

Now I want to change it to

http://januapp.com/demo/search.php?search=bbb
http://januapp.com/demo/search.php?other=bbb

I don't know how can I do it?

I tried this

```
import optparse
import requests
import urlparse


parser = optparse.OptionParser() 

parser.add_option("-t","--Host", dest="Target", help="Please provide the target", default="true") 

options, args = parser.parse_args() 

url = options.Target 

xss = [] 
xss.append("bbb")  

try:

    url2 =urlparse.urlparse(url)    
    print url2
    url3 = urlparse.parse_qs(url2.query)
    parametervalue =  [key for key, key in url3.iteritems()] #[['aaa']]
    parsed =  parametervalue.append(xss[0])
    print parsed
    finalurl = urljoin(url, parsed)
    print finalurl





except Exception as e:
    print e
```

So when I pass this

```
xss3.py -t http://januapp.com/demo/search.php?search=aaa
```

The Error occurs below on to the cmd

```
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='januapp.com', path='/demo/search.php', params='', query='search=aaa', fragment='')
None
name 'urljoin' is not defined
```

See the `None`

Now that's the problem,

I am using Python2.7.

Thank you very much. Hope you get the problem.

Comment: Try using Requests. Link: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: Hey! why you need links working for that? Its just a simple question.

Comment: @Frank I am asking How to change the parameter's value. Please read the question again. I define it very clearly

Comment: Add some sample that you expect and output as well..

Comment: You must be more specific, from your question it seems like you want to change the link and go to other place in a web app. If you want to replace part of text take a look here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace

Comment: @DeyanGeorgiev Hi! Can you please read the question. Then Give me some suggestion based on my try. It will be big help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something with this kind of approach.

```
url = 'http://januapp.com/demo/search.php?search=aaa'

# First get all your query params
arr = url.split('?')
base_url = arr[0] # This is your base url i.e. 'http://januapp.com/demo/search.php'
params = arr[1] # here are your query params ['search=aaa']

# Now seprate out all the query parameters and their values
arr2 = params.split("=") # This will give you somrthing like this : ['search', 'aaa'], the the value will be next to the key

# This is a dictonary to hold the key value pairs
param_value_dict = {} # {'search': 'aaa'}
for i, str in enumerate(arr2):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        param_value_dict[str] = arr2[i + 1]



# now if you want to chnage the value of search from 'aaa' to 'bbb', then just change it in the dictonary
param_value_dict['search'] = 'bbb'

# now form the new url from the dictonary
new_url = base_url + '?'
for param_name, param_value in param_value_dict.items():
    new_url = new_url + param_name + "=" + param_value + "&"

# remove the extra '&'
new_url = new_url[:len(new_url) - 1]
print(new_url)
```

Comment: Okay Again not benefinal, see if there is other parameter not the search. Like this http://januapp.com/demo/search.php?search2=aaa Then I will have to go the code and change it to (url.split('search2=')) which is not beneficial.

Comment: @UtkarshAgrawal Then just split it with =

Comment: No, thats not gonna work. I want it fully automated. Thanks

Comment: @UtkarshAgrawal in that case, you can first split using '?'. This will give you all the query parameters, Then you can change whatever you like.

Comment: This is not the way to answer. Can you show it to me? If you can then it will consider to an answer. Thank you

Comment: @UtkarshAgrawal please check updated answer. Try to understand the answer.

Comment: Now One question i want to ask you now suppose you have `ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='januapp.com', path='/demo/search.php', params='', query='search=aaa', fragment='')`

Comment: Now I want to add this `{'search': 'bbb'}`  in the above parse result. How can i? You got it or not?

Comment: @UtkarshAgrawal what are you trying to ask?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49110713/how-to-add-the-dictionary-in-parse-qs-results see this please

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
ext = "bbb"

a = "http://januapp.com/demo/search.php?search="

print a+ext
```

Where `ext` is what you want to search for, `a` is the link and just add them together.

Or you could replace values like this:

```
ext = "bbb"

a = "http://januapp.com/demo/search.php?search=aaa"

print a.replace('aaa', ext)
```

Using regex:

```
import re

ext = "bbb"

a = "http://januapp.com/demo/search.php?search=aaa"

b=re.compile(r".+search=")

print re.search(b,a).group()+ext
```

Comment: Thanks for answering But its not fair to me. What If the value of search is "aaaaaaa" Then I will have to go to the code and change the value to of replace ('aaaaaa', ext)" Which is not beneficial for me

Comment: @UtkarshAgrawal OK please give me a minute.

Comment: I am so sorry simon. Can you please read the question again. Thank yiou. Really appreciated.